# Prime as well as bind callback

Tags: jquery

If I defined a function to do some work

```
function my_callback() {
  // do stuff ...
}
```

Then bound that function to a custom event on a page element on page load

```
$('#page_region').bind('anEvent', my_callback);
```

If I also wanted to execute the function on page load, would it be possible to do something more elegant than:

```
// prime    
my_callback();
// bind
$('#page_region').on('anEvent', my_callback);
```

Perhaps the actual question is can a function self execute within the definition?

Comment: `my_callback() && $('#page_region').bind('anEvent', my_callback);` ?

Comment: please use `.on`, not `.bind`

Comment: Not sure what you mean metadings? 
I keep forgetting latest fn to use, thanks Alnitak.
Added final sentence to clarify question, because Hkidd answer just different way of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Load function on page load**

You can try to add the function to the jQuery .ready() event.

```
$(document).ready(my_callback);
```

or

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   my_callback();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

After this you can bind the function to another event. For example by pressing a refresh logo:

**With .on():**

```
$(document).on("click", "#your_element", my_callback);
```

**With .click()**:

```
$("#your_element").click(my_callback);
```

The function will always be executed "on page load " and the user will be able to force an execution of the function. I hope this helps and make sure to check the jQuery API documentation for events like .on() and .click()